# how to implement token based authentication in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I want to implement a content based application say based on fetching journals adding to user reading list and first need to check user ip address and then create a login form along with authentication and after that generate a token and the token need to be stored in localstorage and token needs to be accessed till logout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think this is a copy+paste of a question I've seen before in the last day or two. If you have deleted a question and reposted a copy, it is a good idea not to do that - your account can enter a question ban if you do that (especially if some of your questions where downvoted before being deleted).